# Difference between accessing a function and nested function in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to work out why I can not access the nested function in a similar way as I can when I am just accessing an un-nested function (maybe there is a better way to explain this.

**In other words, this works:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Working with elements</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var my_div = null;
var newDiv = null;

function addElement()
{
  // create a new div element
  // and give it some content
  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.

  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}

</script>

<body onload="addElement()">
<div id='org_div1'> The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This does not work:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Working with elements</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var my_div = null;
var newDiv = null;

function addElement()
{
    this.getFieldset = function() {
        // create a new div element
        // and give it some content
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.

        // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
        my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
        document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
    }
}

</script>

<body onload="addElement.getFieldSet()">
<div id='org_div1'> The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the second case, you never call `addElement`, so the code inside of it is never executed. But if you would call it, `this` does not refer to the function itself. `this` is determined by how you call the function. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). In your case, `addElement` does not seem to have to be a function, you could define it as an object instead.

Comment: In the second case `(new addElement).getFieldSet()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you never executed `addElement()` in the second case in order to execute the `this.getFieldset = ...` assignment.

You could change your code to

```
function addElement() {}

addElement.getFieldSet = function() {
        // create a new div element
        // and give it some content
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.

        // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
        my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
        document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
    };
```

**EDIT**

See example at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQHgv/).

Comment: When I changed this over it does not work, I am getting: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'addElement.getFieldSet()')

Comment: @peteskiii Sorry, I just copied a typo from your example. In the definition you wrote `getFieldset`, while in the `onload` you make a call to `getFieldSet`. Edited in my answer.